# Why does this az login command fail in Gitlab CI?

Tags: azure, gitlab, gitlab-ci, azure-cli

I'm trying to run a task within GitLab CI using the official MS Azure-CLI docker image. It fails at the first step, logging in using the "az login" command. I'm using a service principal login with a secret, all stored as GitLab CI variables. Using this command with the CI job:

`az login --service-principal --username="${AZURE_APP_ID}" --password="${AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET}" --tenant=${AZURE_TENANT_ID}`

gives me the error:

`usage error: --service-principal --username NAME --password SECRET --tenant TENANT`

Yet if I run the Azure-CLI docker image locally and run the exact same command it works fine. Why is this not working? What format do I need to use to get the damn thing working?

Comment: First, check if the Azure-CLI is installed in the container. Second, check if the variables are already set.

Comment: It's the official Microsoft Azure CLI container image, of course it's installed. Variables are not already set in the image, they are passed through by GitLab CI.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the error and the task code?

Comment: @Matt Are you able to verify access to those variables from the CI pipeline?

Comment: @CharlesXu: azure-cli must be installed as the error given is the error what azure-cli would return

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Debug with Print Driven Development style.

Before the `az login` line echo all the variables to see if they have the proper values.

I could reproduce the error you provided only in one occasion, when the command line contained this only: `az login --service-principal`

If any more arguments or garbage are provided, the error is different. You should check if Gitlab CI even executes those commands you think it should execute.